# SQL Server where case only if not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select rows following some variables which will switch on or off some conditions, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field =
   CASE @param
       WHEN NULL THEN field
       ELSE @param
   END
```

In another words.. I want to compare only if @param is not null, but my select doesn't work. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code should work except when `field` has a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `@param` is null it will use `field`, when `@param` is not null it will use `@param`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field = ISNULL(@param,field)
```

But `field = field` will always be true.
So what you might want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field = @param
    and @param is not null
```

Answer (score 2):

Why use a Case for a single switch? an OR statement should do the trick.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE @param IS NULL OR Field = @Param
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field =
   CASE 
   WHEN @param IS NULL THEN field
   ELSE @param
END
```